# Editor have not permissions for a plugin

Tags: plugins, editor, permissions

I use static html output plugin to export pages to html, but only the admin can use this plugin.

A editor have not permissions to export a html page. It says: You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page. when a editor try it.

How can I make this plugin available for the editors on my site?

**I found the solution, the plugin has the capability manage_options; I change it to edit_posts**

Comment: Please link to the plugin in question. This might be question better aimed at its developer.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/static-html-output-plugin/